# supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a small CMS on my local WAMP machine.

Once I have exported my project on to the hosting, the following problem shows up

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homepages/36/d288053636/htdocs/MYWEBSITE/admin/index.php on line 44
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/36/d288053636/htdocs/MYWEBSITE/admin/index.php:44) in /homepages/36/d288053636/htdocs/MYWEBSITE/admin/index.php on line 62

LINE 44:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM pureUser WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));
```

Line 62:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

**What does those errors mean?**

Comment: This has nothing to do with your hosting provider.

Comment: It means that the MySQL query was not successful.

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly connect to the database and it has table `pureUser`?

Comment: @crack - yes. Names and connection details are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL query has not finished correctly. You most likely uploaded the script, but have either not uploaded the database, or have wrong database credentials.

**Hint** You can get very good and descriptive error messages when you put the following code after a failing mysql_query statement:

```
if (mysql_error()) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: ``Table 'db380361691.pureUser' doesn't exist`` - I'm sure db name is correct, and table name is correct. Is SQL case-sensitive ?

Comment: Is the table existing on that server? Please double check. Table names are not case sensitive.

Comment: Exist! I have change all to small case and it does work. So it is `case sensitive`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html: **This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.** :( The more you learn...

Answer (score 1):

The first error means means that you're calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on something that isn't a MySQL resource. `mysql_query` is supposed to return a proper resource, so if you're getting this error it probably means that your query failed (something is probably configured wrong).

Due to the way HTTP works, it's impossible to send HTTP headers (such as the Location header) after you've started writing the body of the page. When the first error occurred, it wrote an error message to the body, causing another error when you tried to send the headers to redirect the user. This should go away ince you've fixed your first bug.

Answer (score 0):

It means your query is failing. There are multiple reasons why, including possibly a connection failure to your database or an error in your SQL query. Have you tried debugging to determine if your query syntax is correct?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that after the concatenation, your query is probably invalid.

You should log your query after the concatenation to see if this is the case. You should also test what the `mysql_query` returns before to call `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

On another note:

Is that your true production code ? If this is a public facing site then that's a serious security hole and is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

What if I put in your username field:

```
 1;TRUNCATE pureUser --
```

Your query become:

```
SELECT id,usr FROM pureUser WHERE usr=1; TRUNCATE pureUser -- AND pass=...
```

So, you should try the filter php native extension:

[Data filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Futhermore, you should try PDO, which is more powerful and robust to work with databases:

[PHP Data Objects](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm doing `mysql_real_escape_string` before.

Comment: It is correct, and an important hint, but has nothing to do with the problem.