# Error: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, chat, send, fetch

I got the error "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...". On the lines that concern this mysql query.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from chat order by time desc limit 0,10");
$messages = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $messages[] = "<div class='message'><div class='messagehead'>" . $row[name] . " - " . date('g:i A M, d Y',$row[time]) . "</div><div class='messagecontent'>" . $row[message] . "</div></div>";
   //The last posts date
   $old = $row[time];
}
//Display the messages in an ascending order, so the newest message will be at the bottom
for($i=9;$i>=0;$i--){
   echo $messages[$i];
}
```

Comment: I imagine your query is failing; but you're not checking for that, and just assume it's worked. You should be checking the return from `mysql_query` and handling it appropriately; you'll find the full details of the problem in `mysql_error`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214280/supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: I think no results found first need to check mysql_num_rows then check fetch array.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging here? Make use of `mysql_error` function to see what's wrong with your query. It also helps if you search through the millions of duplicates in the site that has already been answered.

Comment: Yor next notice will be: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' and ...

Comment: Your connection could have failed too, so check that.

Answer (score 1):

Theres an error in your query.

Try to output the error with mysql_error(), e.g.:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from chat order by time desc limit 0,10") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will stop the script and show the sql error.

Answer (score 0):

It means your query is not executed there is some error in it.

you can find out what the error is using mysql_error()

or

you can use

```
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo($row);
```

see if it returns any value. If it returns 1 or value >1 it means your query is working fine else query is not executed.